# Make the last cell of a table row eat all the white space

Tags: css, css-tables

When you make a table 100% wide, the default behavior is to proportionally distribute the width of each cell, so that cells with more text are wider, and cells with less text are narrower.

I want my table to fill the width of the screen, but the cells within should align to the left, as if I hadn't specified a table width. In other words:

[image]

How can I get that nice white space to the right of my table cells while keeping the overall table 100% wide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This css should take care of it:

```
th:last-child, td:last-child {width:100%;}
```

However, that's going to try to squish all the other cells leftward. So you might want to add this for a consistent height in the column headings:

```
thead {white-space:nowrap;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following css and HTML. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L73Lg/1/)**

**CSS**

```
table { 
    width:100%; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #4D4D4D;
    font:12px/17px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, serif; 
    margin-bottom:17px;
}
th { 
    background: #F9D7AB; 
    color: 4D4D4D; 
    font-size: 13px;
}
td { 
    background: #F8E5C3; 
    color: 4D4D4D; 
    font-size: 13px;
}

td, th { 
    padding: 8px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    text-align: left; 
}
```